# VS Code gives error about PHP 5.6 running when PHP 7 is installed

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I just installed VS CODE version 1.10.1 on a Mac computer (os 10.12.3) and then upgraded php to version 7 and verified by placing `phpinfo()` in a script named `info.php` and then running it in the browser to verify that PHP 7 is in use.

After opening this same `info.php` file in VS code I get the following error:

> The language server needs at least PHP 7 installed.
>   Version found: 5.6.28

Do I need to change something in VS Code settings to get it to see the correct PHP version that is running on my Mac?

Will this be different if I am editing a file that is in a Docker container?

Answer (score 3):

1. insure upgrade php to version php7.
   check in your terminal: php -v
2. change vscode settings,
   add bellow line to setting.json:

"php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/local/php5-7.1.4-20170506-100436/bin/php"

Comment: According to VC version 1.71 this configuration parameter is unknown. This may have been a thing back in 2017 tho :)

Comment: @Peng Chen, your answer doesn't help me. Any other fix?

Answer (score 2):

When upgrading to PHP7 from https://php-osx.liip.ch it states:

> php-osx doesn't overwrite the php binaries installed by Apple, but installs everything in /usr/local/php5. The new php binary is therefore in /usr/local/php5/bin/php.

I added this path to my settings.json:

"php.executablePath": "/usr/local/php5/bin/php"

Comment: Did it worked for you with this, my `php -v` works fine but VScode complains about the path being invalid !!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your Path variable.
Open the .bash_profile file in your home directory-

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

and you will see path to PHP version 5.6.28. Change it to path to version 7.x, save the file (ctrl + x), restart VS Code, and you should be good to go